# Java - Reading from and Writing to a Text File

Tags: java

I'm successfully able to read from and write to a sample text file in Java. However, when I try to read from the file, it always throws a NoSuchElementException when it reaches the end of the file. I've modified the code to catch this exception by printing "Reached end of file," but I was wondering if that was normal; I don't feel like it is and I feel like I'm missing something.

Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

MyFileWriter.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyFileWriter {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File file = new File("MyFile.txt");
      PrintWriter out = null;

      try {
         out = new PrintWriter(file);
         out.write("This is a text file.");
      } catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
      } finally {
         out.flush();
         out.close();
      }
   }
}
```

MyFileReader.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyFileReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     File file = new File("MyFile.txt");
     Scanner scan = null;

     try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        while(true) {
           String next = scan.nextLine();
           if(next != null) {
              System.out.println(next);
           }
           else {
              break;
           }
        }
     } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("***Reached end of file***");
     } finally {
        scan.close();
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: @clcto - that fixed it, thank you! I knew it was something like that but I couldn't put my finger on it. It's been a while since I've done I/O stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `while(true)` in the reader, use `while( scan.hasNextLine() )`